# MassTransit - Consumer throws Exception / Publisher times out waiting for response

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am using MassTransit and have the following-ish code in my app:

```
RequestMsg request = buildMeARequest();               
SomeTypeOfResponse response = null;

_serviceBus.PublishRequest(request, c =>
    {
        c.Handle<SomeTypeOfResponse>(message => response = message);
        c.SetTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    });

return response;
```

And on the consumer side, I have something like this:

```
public class RequestMsgConsumer : Consumes<T>.All
{
    public RequestMsgConsumer(IServiceBus serviceBus)
    {

        _serviceBus = serviceBus;
    }

    public void Consume(RequestMsg request)
    {
        SomeTypeOfResponse response = doWorkToGetResponse(request);

        _serviceBus.Context().Publish(response);
    }
}
```

This works great when everything goes well ... however if the `doWorkToGetResponse(request)` throws an exception (or any portion of the `Consume()` method really) the original requestor times out, there is no indication of failure.

My original idea was to build a class like `Either<Exception, SomeTypeOfResponse>` so that the requester always expects this `Either<>` construct, but that is going to force me to always try/catch every consume method - and there are plenty of them.

Has anybody else solved this more elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is to add `c.HandleFault(fault => ...)` to your `PublishRequest`.

If that doesn't work, there's been a couple messages on the mailing list this past week or two on how some fixes will be in the next release. I think the failures was limited to Sagas but I could be wrong.